# Drupal: script all admin settings for site cloning

Tags: configuration, quiz

I am a newbie Drupal user here, tasked with an exam taking site for a school.

I have run a docker container with version 7.69 and installed Quiz and few other modules, made a lot of settings via an admin GUI, like enabled few modules, added module settings etc. Added some taxonomy and some content (questions and a quiz).

Now I'd like to spin up a production site, but I can't imagine doing it all over with the admin GUI.

Is there a way to dump the whole site configuration, bar the content, and apply it to a newly deployed vanilla version? Ideally, I'd put some commands in a Dockerfile, but really any option that does not involve hours of clicking through admin pages...

I have looked at Features, but I am not sure this is my way. I.e. if I understood correctly, the modules I use must support it, and they don't.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Other than dumping your database into a new database, Features is how you would do this.

Comment: Thanks, @Kevin! Do I understand correctly, that I really want a one-click deployment, then I'd rather create a new module where I code all my configuration settings in PHP?